# Hibernate show_sql not showing actual query sent to db

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, db2

It seems what's logged by `show_sql` is not what's actually sent to the data base (in this case, it's a DB2 instance).

This is logged by the application:

```sql
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        table
        (id, col1, col2, col3, col4) 
    values
        (default, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

(`id` is an `IDENTITY` column).

But the DB2 server reports this query:

```sql
select id from final table (insert into table (id, col1, col2, col3, col4) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?))
```

This is perfectly reasonable - hibernate needs the id that was generated by the db to update the entity, and this syntax seems to be the recommended way for DB2. However, I expected that the actual query would be logged.

This was observed in a Spring Boot application using JPA repositories, with hibernate as the implementation.

If I run the `insert` with a database client, or if I specify the `insert` manually (`@Query(..., nativeQuery=true)`) then the DB2 log shows just the insert.

My guess is that the db2 driver changes the query, probably because of the need to retrieve the newly generated id. Is that correct? And is there any way to log the actual queries, without using an interceptor such as those used to view the bound parameters?

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is controlled by the  `useIdentityValLocalForAutoGeneratedKeys` property turned off by default.

> **useIdentityValLocalForAutoGeneratedKeys**
> Specifies whether the IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ uses only the SQL built-in function IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL to determine automatically generated key values.
> The data type of this property is boolean.
>
> Possible values are:
>
> **true**
> Specifies that the IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ always uses the SQL built-in function IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL to determine automatically generated key values. The driver uses IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL even if it is possible to use SELECT FROM INSERT.
> Specify true if the target data server supports SELECT FROM INSERT, but the target objects do not. For example, SELECT FROM INSERT is not valid for a table on which a trigger is defined.
>
> **false**
> Specifies that the IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ determines whether to use SELECT FROM INSERT or IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL to determine automatically generated keys. **false is the default**.

[Common IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ properties for Db2 servers](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=pdsdjs-common-data-server-driver-jdbc-sqlj-properties-db2-servers)

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is probably the driver that changes the request. You can check which query is sent to the server by the application by using [VisualVm](https://visualvm.github.io/). It has an option to profile the requests sent by the driver :

[image]

Just connect to the application, start the JDBC Profiler and launch the request. You will see the request in the 'profiling results'